# I have converted my angular application from 15 to 16, getting library (angular-progress-http) which declares ProgressHttpModule is not compatible

Tags: angular16

I have converted my application to angular 16 from angular 15, getting error when given command npm start related to import { ProgressHttpModule } from 'angular-progress-http'; package. I do not see any red lines(error) in the vscode related to package but in terminal it shows error. I have tried npm install again by deleting node_module and package-lock.json but didnt work. Any solution would be appreciated.
[image]

I do have latest version of anular-progress-http included(1.0.0). And I dont have any errors or red lines in other files or dependent one, but i get this error only in terminal when given npm start.

Comment: It looks like angular-progress-http deprecated:https://github.com/DarkXaHTeP/angular-progress-http

Comment: Hi @Chellappanவ, thank you for your answer. But in the npm doc "https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-progress-http?activeTab=versions" shows 1.0.0 is the latest and last version. If there is any latest version which one i should install.

Comment: It was published long ago. I dont think it will support latest version of angular

Comment: Hi @Chellappanவ, thank you for answer. Is there any work around for it..?

Comment: Lib author suggesting http core lib [DEPRECATED] Use @angular/common/http instead

Comment: Yes, I am using @angular/common/http, any other work around or hack we have...?

Comment: may be you can fork this:github.com/DarkXaHTeP/angular-progress-http and publish your own version

Comment: ok thank you ll try doing that